# Angular 8: ngx-chips issue

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

Getting below error for importing ngx-chips in my module.
My angular version is 8 and ngx-chips version is "ngx-chips": "^2.0.0-beta.0",

getting below error>>
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.mjs 644:36-48
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.mjs 649:12-24
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.mjs 667:24-36
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.mjs 31:18-27
Can't import the named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.mjs 219:18-27
Can't import the named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.mjs 458:18-27
Can't import the named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.mjs 606:18-27
Can't import the named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.mjs 618:22-34
Can't import the named export 'ContentChild' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

My dependencies are:

"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.5",
"@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/common": "8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
"@angular/core": "8.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
"@angular/router": "8.0.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.5.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "15.0.0",
"ag-grid-angular": "19.1.2",
"ag-grid-community": "19.1.3",
"angular-2-local-storage": "^3.0.2",
"angular-tree-component": "8.0.0",
"angular2-text-mask": "9.0.0",
"angularx-social-login": "^2.2.1",
"bootstrap": "4.3.1",
"chart.js": "2.7.3",
"classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
"codemirror": "5.42.0",
"core-js": "2.5.4",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9",
"easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
"enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
"flot": "themicon/flot",
"fullcalendar": "3.9.0",
"ika.jvectormap": "themicon/ika.jvectormap",
"intl": "1.2.5",
"jqcloud2": "2.0.3",
"jquery": "3.4.1",
"jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
"jquery-sparkline": "2.4.0",
"jquery.browser": "0.1.0",
"jquery.flot.spline": "themicon/jquery.flot.spline",
"jquery.flot.tooltip": "github:krzysu/flot.tooltip",
"lodash": "4.17.12",
"modernizr": "3.7.1",
"moment": "2.22.2",
"ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
"ng2-dnd": "5.0.2",
"ng2-file-upload": "1.3.0",
"ng2-img-cropper": "0.9.0",
"ng2-material-dropdown": "0.10.1",
"ng2-table": "1.3.2",
"ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "4.2.0",
"ngx-chips": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
"ngx-color-picker": "7.0.2",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^2.3.0",
"ngx-infinite-scroll": "6.0.1",
"ngx-select-ex": "3.6.7",
"ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
"popper.js": "1.14.3",
"rxjs": "6.4.0",
"rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
"screenfull": "3.3.3",
"simple-line-icons": "2.4.1",
"source-sans-pro": "2.40.0",
"spinkit": "1.2.5",
"summernote": "0.8.10",
"sweetalert": "2.1.2",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
"ts-md5": "^1.2.7",
"tslib": "1.9.0",
"weather-icons": "github:erikflowers/weather-icons",
"web-animations-js": "2.2.1",
"zone.js": "0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
"@angular/cli": "8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "8.0.0",
"@types/codemirror": "0.0.67",
"@types/jasmine": "3.3.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
"@types/lodash": "4.14.118",
"@types/node": "10.12.3",
"codelyzer": "5.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
"karma": "4.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.5",
"karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.0",
"karma-read-json": "1.1.0",
"loaders.css": "0.1.2",
"protractor": "5.4.0",
"ts-node": "7.0.0",
"tslint": "5.16.0",
"typescript": "3.4.3",
"webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
}